# Using JAVA, how to iterate (or traverse?) through json file with more than one level of data?

Tags: java, json

I have a snippet of a snippet of a json file that has 3 levels of key,value data I need to access.  The tricky part is, sometimes it's a list and sometimes a tuple (or I can be corrected).  Some have referred to this file as a map of maps, but I'm guessing that's just nested hashmaps.

Problem Statement:  I can iterate through the first level of this JSON, but cannot iterate through the lists inside "data".  Java barks at me saying I can't do that with a string.  Sometimes the values under data/(next level random word) starts with a bracket [ then a squiggly and sometimes just a squiggly {.

There will be a few lines in there that won't make sense because I was trying different methods to unwrap those sublists.

```
Key is: raindrop, Value is : {".type":"uri",".value":"http:blahblahblah.info"}
Key is: apex, Value is : [{".type":"inet4",".value":"3.3.3.3"},{".type":"inet4",".value":"3.3.3.3"},{".type":"inet4",".value":"3.3.3.3"},{".type":"inet4",".value":"3.3.3.3"},{".type":"inet4",".value":"3.3.3.3"}]
```

This is the example of the json file I'm trying to cycle through to get these values so I can determine what kind of value it has (switch statement to count distinctive types).

```
{
        "data": {
            "coffee": [
                {
                    ".type": "bigdec",
                    ".value": "2626262626.234234234234234"
```

And here is what I have so far that just gives me the first layer of data.

````
package com.mycompany.app;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;
import org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser;
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Map;
import java.io.FileReader;

public class App {
    private static Object object;

    public void countDistinctValues(String[] args){}


    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception 
    {
        String filePath = "D:/sandbox/map03/my-app/data.json";
        // parsing file 
        Object obj = new JSONParser().parse(new FileReader(filePath));

        
        // typecasting obj to JSONObject
        JSONObject jo = (JSONObject) obj;

        System.out.println("--------------------------------------------------------------------");

        Map theData = ((Map)jo.get("data"));
        
        Map<String, String> runningMap =  new HashMap<>();  
        Map<String, String> tempMap =  new HashMap<>(); 
        int matchCount  = 0;
        // iterating address Map
        Iterator<Map.Entry> itr1 = theData.entrySet().iterator();
        while (itr1.hasNext()) {
            Map.Entry pair = itr1.next();
            // System.out.println(pair.getKey() + " : " + pair.getValue());  
            runningMap.put(pair.getKey().toString(),pair.getValue().toString());
        }
        //    THIS ENTIRE SECTION BELOW IS TO JUST TRYING TO COUNT EACH LEVEL - THOUGHT I COULD TAKE THE VALUE INTO A VARIABLE AND THEN ITERATE THROUGH IT, BUT IT ONLY SEES IT AS A STRING
        System.out.println("--------------------------------------------------------------------");
        for (Map.Entry<String, String> newPair : runningMap.entrySet()) {
            System.out.println(String.format("Key is: %s, Value is : %s", newPair.getKey(), newPair.getValue()));           
            String pattern = ".*type.*";
            boolean matches = Pattern.matches(pattern, newPair.getValue());
            if (matches == true) {matchCount++; }}
        System.out.println("--------------------------------------------------------------------");
        System.out.println("matches = " + matchCount);

          
            System.out.println("--------------------------------------------------------------------");
            // System.out.println("Test Data --> " + newPair);
        }    
                
         /* for (Map.Entry<String, String> book: pair.entrySet()) {
            System.out.println("key: " + book.getKey() + " value: " + book.getValue());
            }  */      
            }
        ```
````

Comment: Thing is: the JSON parser will automatically parse your data into the corresponding SUBCLASSES. Meaning: when a child element is a list, it will be a JSONArray, otherwise it is a JSONMap. So **depending** on the child class type, your code needs to different things. If it is a list: iterate it. If it is not a list, then it is a map, and you can check for its keys and values and so on.

Comment: Thank you for the info @GhostCat!  So should I do something like this:  pair.getValue().toString().isArray() == true, then try to iterate as it's a list? What about if it's a hash inside a string list?

Comment: Actually, let me ask that differently.  How do I determine what the child class type is?

Comment: Every time when we want to parse JSON objects we must preliminary know what fields this JSON object contains. If you work with backend devs you and backend devs must come to one agreement how JSON object must look like.
If you could not come to agreement, it will be risky for you to parse any type of JSON object, because JSON object's entity may change and your app will crush.

Comment: To parse JSON objects you can use `https://github.com/google/gson`. If easy to use and you code will be clean and simple.

Comment: @JeenbekKhydyr That is simply not true. The OP already knows how to parse, it is not about recommending another library to them. Where, I agree: gson or Jackson have much better interfaces to work with. Then:  you dont always know all fields in advance. Sure, there must be some common understanding, but your tooling should always be pretty robust and only enforce those aspects that are absolutely mandatory.

Comment: Just see what `instanceof` does for you ... remember that you are iterating the child objects, so each child you can do `if (x instanceof JSONArray)` for example. But Jeenbek has one good point: if you are serious about working with JSON, consider to use a more advanced library, such as gson or jackson.